# Find the sum of odd numbers from a string of numbers in python

Tags: python, sum

the question asks to find the sum of odd numbers when given a string of numbers.
so for example, if we are given "123" we should get the sum of 4.

This is my attempt and it returns '4' which is incorrect

```
def sumoddnum(s):
    total= 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i % 2 == 1:
            total += i
    return total 
print(sumoddnum('12345'))
```

I've also tried converting s into integers but it keeps giving me the "int is not iterable" error

```
def sumoddnum(s):
    total= 0
    s= int(s)
    for i in s:
        if i % 2 == 1:
            total += i
    return total 
print(sumoddnum('12345'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```py
def sumoddnum(s):
  return sum(0 if int(i) % 2 == 0 else int(i) for i in s)
```

or if you want to keep your first attempt, you should iterate through your `str` then check the condition on every `int` of character:

```py
def sumoddnum(s):
    total= 0
    for i in s:
        if int(i) % 2 == 1:
            total += int(i)
    return total 
print(sumoddnum('12345'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using a regex approach here.  We can apply the regex pattern `[13579]` to the input string, then use a list comprehension on the resulting list of odd digits to find the sum:

```
num = "123"
odds = re.findall(r'[13579]', num)
sum = sum(int(odd) for odd in odds)
print("the sum is: " + str(sum))
```

This prints:

```
The sum is: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach does not work because what you're actually adding to the sum are 'indices' of `s` not it's elements. What could have work is changing your `for` loop to run over elements instead of their positions. Then keep in mind that elements of a string are characters so a conversion to the int is required. This can be done with built-in `int` function whenever the character actually represents a digit.

```
def sumoddnum(s):
    total= 0
    for i in s:
        if int(i) % 2 == 1:
            total += int(i)
    return total
```

Now at this point you may wonder

> what a long function for such a simple task!

and you'll be absolutely right. Luckily, Python comes with comprehensions which allow us to shorten some of the `for` loops and built-in `sum` function which purpose is kinda self-explanatory but what you need to remember that it takes iterables as its input.

The result you may get will be something like this:

```
def sumoddnum(s):
    return sum(int(i) for i in s if int(i) % 2 == 1)
```

With Python 3.8 you can also make use of brand new walrus operator:

```
def sumoddnum(s):
    return sum(num for i in s if (num := int(i)) % 2 == 1)
```

The problem with your second approach is already explained by the Python interpreter itself. You've converted your string to the integer, and there's no built-in way too loop over integers. You'll need to find and implement your own way to loop over integer's digits (hint: use remainder modulo 10).

Answer (score 1):

The reason your program is not working is because of the line:

```
for i in range(len(str)):
```

here, you are taking all values of i from 0 to the length of the string (exclusive of length).

This means, you are adding up all the odd numbers from 0 to the length of the String.

Instead do this:

```
for i in str:
```

this will give you each character in the string as i. Now:

```
i = int(i)
```

will convert it to int.

Finally :

```
if i%2 == 1: 
    total+=i
```

the final code will be:

```
def sumoddnum(s):
    total= 0
    for i in s:
        i = int(i)
        if i % 2 == 1:
            total += i
    return total 
print(sumoddnum('12345'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumoddnum(s):
    total= 0
    for i in s:
        i = int(i)
        if i % 2 == 1:
            total += i
    return total 
print(sumoddnum('12345'))
```

if you use 'range(len(s))' in for loop instead of 's', it will give you [0,1,2,3,4] which is 0 to length of the '12345.

Therefore, it is required to change the range by just s, then it will give you ['1','2','3','4','5'] which is char elements of string '12345'.

Don't forget to change the type of i to int!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a better and more readable solution:

```
def add_up(n: str or int):
   if type(n) == str and str(n).isdigit():
       numbers = [int(n) for n in list(n.strip()) if int(n) % 2 != 0]
       return sum(numbers)
   elif type(n) == int:
       numbers = [int(str(n)) for n in list(str(n)) if n % 2 != 0]
       return sum(numbers)
   else:
       return "No digits found to add up"
```

Comment: This is absolutely not better and more readable. Your type annotations alone are incorrect (use `Union[]`, not `or`. Never use `type(...) ==`, use `isinstance()`, or in rare cases, test for identity. You test for str then convert to str redundantly. The code repeats itself where a simple `str()` call to convert the input to a sting would suffice.